# Click button to increment/decrement a loop

Tags: excel, vba

[To Explain What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHCe8.jpg)   [Input Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CPQc.jpg)    [User form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/056Qi.jpg)

I have defined the variables on my sheet.2 within text boxes, and on my VBA form (Sheet.1) I have a Plus command button and a Minus command Button, I want the loop to progress only when any of these buttons are clicked.

'**** Function to determine Layer ID of the Sources and define their Elevation and Rotation Angle

```
Function LayerID()
Sheet2.NumberOfSunPositionsBox.Enabled = False
Sheet2.NumberOfSunPositionsBox.Enabled = False
Sheet1.AngleOfRotationBox.Enabled = False
Sheet1.AngleOfElevationBox.Enabled = False

Dim RotationStep, MinRotation, MaxRotation, ElevatioStep, MinElevation, MaxElevation As Integer

RotationStep = Sheet2.RotationStepBox
MinRotation = Sheet2.MinRotationlAngleBox
MaxRotation = Sheet2.MaxRotationAngleBox
ElevationStep = Sheet2.ElevationStepBox
MinElevation = Sheet2.MinElevationAngleBox
MaxElevation = Sheet2.MaxElevationAngleBox

NumberOfRotations = (MaxRotation - MinRotation) / RotationStep + 1
NumberOfElevations = (MaxElevation - MinElevation) / ElevationStep + 1
NumberOfSunPositions = NumberOfRotations * NumberOfElevations
    If MaxElevation = 90 Then
    NumberOfSunPositions = NumberOfSunPositions + 1
    End If

Sheet2.NumberOfSunPositionsBox = NumberOfSunPositions
Sheet1.AngleOfElevationBox = MinElevation
Sheet1.AngleOfRotationBox = MinRotation
'Power1 = 0
'Power2 = 100

    For Elevation = MinElevation To MaxElevation Step ElevationStep
'        If Sheet1.ElevationPlusButton Then
           If LayerNumber <= NumberOfSunPositions Then
           Sheet1.ElevationPlusButton.Enabled = True
                    If Elevation = 90 Then
                    Rotation = 0
                    LayerNumber = LayerNumber + 1
                    Debug.Print ("Layer ID:" & LayerNumber & " E:" & Elevation & " R:" & Rotation)
                    Sheet1.AngleOfElevationBox = Elevation
                    Else
                        For Rotation = MinRotation To MaxRotation Step RotationStep
'                        If Sheet1.RotationPlusButton Then
'                            Sheet1.RotationPlusButton.enable = True
                            LayerNumber = LayerNumber + 1
                            Debug.Print ("Layer ID:" & LayerNumber & " E:" & Elevation & " R:" & Rotation)
                            Sheet1.AngleOfRotationBox = Rotation
'                        End If
                        Next Rotation
                    End If
            End If
'        End If
    Next Elevation
End Function
```

Comment: Not quite clear on what you mean.  You have a `UserForm` named `Sheet1` - _not_ a `Worksheet`, but a form inserted within the VBE?  And the loop you mean is the `For Elevation = MinElevation To MaxElevation Step ElevationStep` loop?

Comment: I don't have a user form separately, my user form is on sheet.1 and the loop I want to run is elevation and rotation. for both the loop to increment or decrement I want my button to work. This macro is for controlling another piece of software which support macro control

Comment: Ah ok, so it's a `Worksheet` made to look like a form.

Comment: it is not clear what you mean by loop to progress by command button, if i am thinking of what you trying to achieve then may please think of simple possibility of using a spinner (may be linked to a cell) for and using spinner value as elevation.. The vba could be (with some modification) could be attached to cell change detected via `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, Please see the attached images, maybe that helps clarify what I mean. if I run my code, it progresses with 10degree step, gives me the value of the elevation rotation and its layer ID. Since I am controlling the layer id of another software, I need a click function which makes the loop execute only once so that the layer id of other software can be controlled.

Comment: So what is supposed to happen when `MinElevation`, `MaxElevation`, or `ElevationStep` change between button clicks?

Comment: after the button click works and the loop goes to next layer ID, I will call another function (source function) which will update the layer function of my VR file (Switch on/off corresponding sun position in the VR file)... in the code where I am debugging  the line will be replaced to call my source function.

Comment: Would you kindly help us understand the followings 1. Do you want to halt the code execution, so that it will run again on button click?  2. What  variable/s you want to increase or decrease with button click? _(both elevation and rotation are only increased in the code) _ 3. Why the code is to run as function and not as sub? (It returns no values. though it may used to call some other software)

Comment: Hi Ahmad, Thanks for looking into this... 1. Yes, that is correct, however, the code should check the button click minus/plus and then proceed to decrease/increase the elevation with same the elevation step. same goes for the rotation as well. 2. Elevation and Rotation both need to increase/decrease.  3.unfortunately, I am not familiar with the basics of coding hence all the codes I have written are as the function. This function name is LayerID and in the code, I have a variable called LayerNumber, with each click the value of LayerNumber will be used to execute the functionality of my softw

Comment: Hi Ahmed, Please see the attached Image (To Explain What I need). Hopefully, it will be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

What I could understand from the details

1. There is no need to loop for manual operation and the `layerNumber` could be simply derived from the `TextBox` values (or directly from Cells) with the formula 
   `LayerNumber = ((Elevation - MinElevation) / ElevationStep) * NumberOfRotations + (Rotation - MinRotation) / RotationStep`
2. Rotation & Elevation Plus & Minus buttons (or spinners) could be used for increase or decrease Rotation & Elevation with the steps,Max, Min defined.
3. Finally VR software could be called from any button click with the help of `LayerID`
   I tried it like this to generate `LayerID` according to already made buttons etc.

Buttons names, Sheet names etc may be changed according to your need. if my assumptions are not correct feel free to further describe your need.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub ElvMinus_Click()
Dim ElevationStep, MinElevation, MaxElevation, Elevation As Integer
ElevationStep = Val(Sheet2.ElevationStepBox.Text)
MinElevation = Val(Sheet2.MinElevationAngleBox.Text)
MaxElevation = Val(Sheet2.MaxElevationAngleBox.Text)
Elevation = Val(Sheet2.AngleOfElevationBox.Text)
Elevation = Elevation - ElevationStep
Elevation = IIf(Elevation < MinElevation, MinElevation, Elevation)
Sheet2.AngleOfElevationBox.Text = Elevation
GetLayerID
End Sub
Private Sub ElvPlus_Click()
Dim ElevationStep, MinElevation, MaxElevation, Elevation As Integer
ElevationStep = Val(Sheet2.ElevationStepBox.Text)
MinElevation = Val(Sheet2.MinElevationAngleBox.Text)
MaxElevation = Val(Sheet2.MaxElevationAngleBox.Text)
Elevation = Val(Sheet2.AngleOfElevationBox.Text)
Elevation = Elevation + ElevationStep
Elevation = IIf(Elevation > MaxElevation, MaxElevation, Elevation)
Sheet2.AngleOfElevationBox.Text = Elevation
GetLayerID
End Sub
Private Sub RotMinus_Click()
Dim RotationStep, MinRotation, MaxRotation, Rotation As Integer
RotationStep = Val(Sheet2.RotationStepBox.Text)
MinRotation = Val(Sheet2.MinRotationAngleBox.Text)
MaxRotation = Val(Sheet2.MaxRotationAngleBox.Text)
Rotation = Val(Sheet2.AngleOfRotationBox.Text)
Rotation = Rotation - RotationStep
Rotation = IIf(Rotation < MinRotation, MinRotation, Rotation)
Sheet2.AngleOfRotationBox.Text = Rotation
GetLayerID
End Sub
Private Sub RotPlus_Click()
Dim RotationStep, MinRotation, MaxRotation, Rotation As Integer
RotationStep = Val(Sheet2.RotationStepBox.Text)
MinRotation = Val(Sheet2.MinRotationAngleBox.Text)
MaxRotation = Val(Sheet2.MaxRotationAngleBox.Text)
Rotation = Val(Sheet2.AngleOfRotationBox.Text)
Rotation = Rotation + RotationStep
Rotation = IIf(Rotation > MaxRotation, MaxRotation, Rotation)
Sheet2.AngleOfRotationBox.Text = Rotation
GetLayerID
End Sub
Private Sub GetLayerID()
Dim RotationStep, ElevationStep, MinRotation, MaxRotation, ElevatioStep, MinElevation, MaxElevation As Integer
Dim NumberOfRotations, NumberOfElevations, NumberOfSunPositions As Integer
Dim Elevation, Rotation, layerNumber As Integer
RotationStep = Val(Sheet2.RotationStepBox.Text)
MinRotation = Val(Sheet2.MinRotationAngleBox.Text)
MaxRotation = Val(Sheet2.MaxRotationAngleBox.Text)
ElevationStep = Val(Sheet2.ElevationStepBox.Text)
MinElevation = Val(Sheet2.MinElevationAngleBox.Text)
MaxElevation = Val(Sheet2.MaxElevationAngleBox.Text)

NumberOfRotations = (MaxRotation - MinRotation) / RotationStep + 1
NumberOfElevations = (MaxElevation - MinElevation) / ElevationStep + 1
NumberOfSunPositions = NumberOfRotations * NumberOfElevations
Sheet2.NumberOfSunPositionsBox.Text = NumberOfSunPositions

Elevation = Val(Sheet2.AngleOfElevationBox.Text)
Rotation = Val(Sheet2.AngleOfRotationBox.Text)
layerNumber = ((Elevation - MinElevation) / ElevationStep) * NumberOfRotations + (Rotation - MinRotation) / RotationStep
Sheet2.layerNumber.Text = layerNumber
' Here call to VR  Software
End Sub
```

Comment: Please note that without explicitly specifying a data type (or object type) as e.g. in `Dim ElevationStep, MinElevation, MaxElevation, Elevation As Integer`, only the *last* variable `Elevation` is declared as `Integer`; all other variables will be treated as **Variant by default**!  A consistent declaration is as follows: `Dim ElevationStep As Integer, MinElevation As Integer,  MaxElevation As Integer, Elevation As Integer` :-)

Comment: Thank very much Ahmed AU, this is very good, I just tried your code and with some minor tweaks,  it is doing what it should do. Thanks a ton for your help.